# Swift public func not being exported from framework

Tags: swift, xcode

I created a Swift Framework project in Xcode and I'm trying to export a function for Unity to call. I defined the function like this.

```
@_cdecl("showPaymentForm")
public func showPaymentSheet()-> PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController?{
    NSLog("In showPaymentForm - Navtive code.")
    return ApplePayLib.showPaymentSheet(label: "something", total: 9.99, mainViewController: nil)
```

I ran

```
nm -gU
```

against the binary and it doesn't show any functions exported called showPaymentForm. I check the "Symbols Hidden by Default" to make sure it was set to "No".

If I do the same as above in a package instead of a framework, it works fine. I didn't stick with the package project because I need to include other packages that didn't play nice with it.

Not really sure what else to check.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out the issue was due to the swift file not having a target selected. Once I selected the correct target, the function as exported correctly.